# Git branch, diff, etc not showing any output in terminal, when there should be legitimate output

Tags: git

Here is some terminal output showing what's happening:

```
user@user-work:~/org/admin_app$ git diff
user@user-work:~/org/admin_app$ git branch
user@user-work:~/org/admin_app$ git diff > /tmp/diff.txt
user@user-work:~/org/admin_app$ cat /tmp/diff.txt 
diff --git a/software_prof b/software_prof
index b740d44..078ac0b 160000
--- a/software_prof
+++ b/software_prof
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit b740d44832237d859041ec6b62d77884d3dd87f5
+Subproject commit 078ac0b8908327214448de4de400ae848c482c62-dirty
user@user-work:~/org/admin_app$ git branch > /tmp/branch.txt
user@user-work:~/org/admin_app$ cat /tmp/branch.txt 
* user-dev
  master
```

As you can see the output is readable only when it's output to a file.
The only options in my ~/.gitconfig are for user and email.
Here is the output of `git status`, it doesn't have any problems showing output in the terminal.

```
[user@user-work ~/iaa/admin_app]$ git status
On branch user-dev
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   software_proj (new commits, untracked content)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .pytest_cache/
    build_docker.py
    files_to_copy/etc/environment

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

UPDATE: Here is some more output:

```
[user@user-work ~/org/admin_app]$ git branch
[user@user-work ~/org/admin_app]$ git branch | cat 
* user-dev
  master
[user@user-work ~/org/admin_app]$ git config -l
[user@user-work ~/org/admin_app]$ git config -l | cat 
user.email=user@org.edu
user.name=John Smith
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
submodule.--force.url=git@github.org.edu:ORG/pygsal
submodule.--force.active=true
submodule.pygsal.url=git@github.org.edu:ORG/pygsal
submodule.pygsal.active=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.org.edu:ORG/admin_app.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Comment: `git branch` does not return anything also ??

Comment: Try `git config -l` and if that produces no output the redirect-then-cat trick.

Comment: @jthill I added the git config -l output

Comment: I'd bet something is wrong with your pager. Does `git --no-pager <cmd>` work better?

Comment: the no-pager works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got a great hint from @torek in the comments. It seems related to the pager.

Using this config option let's me use the commands normally:

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager "less -F -X"
```